# Profiler not showing logs on Front-End but showing on Back-End on Magento 1.9.x

Tags: magento-1.9, debugging, frontend-error, profiler

I have been trying to debug or troubleshoot my Magento Store (version 1.9.2.1) for a few days now. It's bottlenecking and hitting the server resource limits. But I am stuck on trying to get my profiler work. It's working and showing logs on the back-end but on front-end there's only empty columns and rows.

This is my Front-End -

[image]

And this is my Back-End -

[image]

I have tried to configure the debugger on my multilingual store views, but still not working. Is there any possible solution to it? `Varien_Profiler::enable();` also uncommented on index.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled the theme and it worked flawlessly. Also, some of my wrapper div's had `display:none;` in the CSS file before reinstallation, which interrupted with the profiler to trace. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on multi-store installation, then you will need to edit each index.php file for each store view. Note that each store view will have its own directory in your magento root directory